# Find Duplicate in many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database table which maps a many to many relation. The database table contains two columns, which are foreign keys from other tables. So this database table only exists for assigning the foreign key from table A to the foreign key from table B.

**The structure of the table**

column 1: conditionID (int11) (foreign key) 
column 2: packageID (int11) (foreign key)

```
CREATE TABLE `many_to_many_table` (
    `conditionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `packageID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `many_to_many_table`
ADD KEY `conditionID` (`conditionID`,`packageID`);
```

I want to find out, if a combination in this table exists. For example a user has the conditions with the IDs 1, 2 and 3. With these IDs a package with the ID 1 already exists. The entries are 1 | 1, 1 | 2 and 1 | 3.

**Sample data**

```
INSERT INTO `many_to_many_table` (`conditionID`, `packageID`) VALUES
(1, 195), (2, 195), (3, 195), (4, 197), (5, 197), (5, 209), (6, 198), (6, 211), (6, 219), (6, 220);
```

With this sample data the query should return the packageID 195.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    packageID,
    conditionID,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            many_to_many_table
        WHERE 
            conditionID IN (1,2,3)
    ) AS rowCount
FROM
    many_to_many_table
GROUP BY
    packageID
HAVING
    conditionID IN (1,2,3)
AND
    rowCount = 3
```

This worked fine in the first moment. But it selects entries which have only the conditionID 1 or conditionID 2 and a different packageID. This query is not exact enough to get duplicates.

Is this possible with one query?

Comment: So you have a certain sequence of conditionIDs and you want to know whether there is a packageID that pair with all these conditionIDs? Is it possible that such packageID pair with also some different conditionID?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to know if there is a packageID with all these condition IDs. It is not possible, that there 's the same packageID with different conditionIDs.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @Strawberry. I added the CREATE Statement and sample data.

Comment: Cool. And the rest?

Comment: Also the table in your CREATE and the table in your INSERT are different. That's not very useful for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want:

```
SELECT packageID
FROM    many_to_many_table
WHERE conditionId IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY    packageID
HAVING SUM(conditionId = 1) > 0
  AND SUM(conditionId = 2) > 0
  AND SUM(conditionId = 3) > 0;
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ac2948107c73a132b2c7da292e91cc74)**

Comment: Works like a charme. Thank you very much.